# Tree level gravity + SM

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let's write the Standard Model action, replace the Lorentz metric with the GR metric, add the Einstein-Hilbert action, and expand the metric to the first order around the flat one. Do we get anything meaningful this way? Are there regions / regimes in our universe where it would make sense to consider such a theory? (Gravity is strong enough so that it should be taken into account at the particle level yet weak enough so that the semi-classical approximation could be used.)

Comment: You might be interested in these review papers: 

- [Quantum Gravity in Everyday Life: General Relativity as an Effective Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0311082)

- [The effective field theory treatment of quantum gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3511)

- [Gravity and Effective Field Theory: A Talk for Phenomenologists](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9512287)

- [Introduction to the Effective Field Theory Description of Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512024)

Comment: Wow, thank you!